# How can i show crosssell products on product page?

Tags: magento2

I have added crosssell products to a product but it's only showing on cart page.
I want to show them on product page. How can i do that on Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to extend "catalog_product_view.xml" in your frontend. Then you can show it in Tabs or in place of "Related Articles" section depending on your choice. You'll have to choose appropriate reference container in your xml. For example
`<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">`
is for adding new tab.